# Tkinter widget unable to be removed (created by a for loop)

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, widget

I have created a variety of Tkinter widgets with for loops. All of them remove fine, except for the "lock_btn" widget. When I press that button the lock button stays on the page (although the rest of the code in the function works). I have tried both with and without globals (the code you see includes globals).

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox

#Setting properties for the window
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Shutdown Timer")
window.geometry("250x300")
window.configure(background="black")

def Login():
    for x in range(0,5):
        login_window[x].pack_forget()


def Auth():
    if usr.get() == "isensedemons":
        if pas.get() == password:
            Login()
        else:
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Login Error", "Incorrect Username or Password")
    else:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Login Error", "Incorrect Username or Password")

def Lock():
    global lock_btn
    for x in range(0,1):
        lock_btn.pack_forget() 

    for x in range(0,5):
        login_window[x].pack()


lock_btn = tkinter.Button(window, text="Lock", fg="white", bg="black", command=Lock)
lbl_usr = tkinter.Label(window, text="Username", fg="white", bg="black")
usr = tkinter.Entry(window)
lbl_pas = tkinter.Label(window, text="Password", fg="white", bg="black")
pas = tkinter.Entry(window, show="•")
btn = tkinter.Button(window, text="Authenticate", fg="white", bg="black", command=Auth)
password = "password"
login_window = [lbl_usr,usr,lbl_pas,pas,btn]

class Create():
    lock_btn.pack()
    lock_btn.place(rely=1, relx=1, anchor="se")

Create()
#Starts the Program
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start by calling `lock_btn.pack(0)`, then you switch to using `place(...)`. So, the widget is being managed by place because it can be only managed by one geometry manager. When you call `pack_forget` it has no effect because `pack` isn't in control of the widget.

Comment: Thanks for that man! Any idea how I would fix this and still be able to place the widget?

Comment: Never mind, i fixed the problem with your initial comment. Thanks!